# Spread function Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows

Tags: r, tidyr

I am converting long to large dataset based on zip code. Some values (intermediate and actual names) can be similar.  Spread function from tidyr returns me an error.

```
zip <- c(02183, 02183, 02184, 02184)
name <- c("Chevregni", "Chevrigny", "Chevresis", "Chevresis")
type <- c("actual_name", "intermediate_name", "actual_name", "intermediate_name")

dummy <- data.frame(zip, name, type)
library(tidyr)
test <- dummy %>% spread(zip, type, name)
```

Expected result :

```
zip     actual_name      intermediate_name  
02183   Chevregny        Chevresix
02184   Chevresis       Chevresis
```

Error : 
Duplicate identifiers for rows

Comment: `Chevresix` is not in the original data ...

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post.

Comment: `df %>% spread(type, name)` works for me

Comment: Didn't I just duped this question? Did you repost the same one?

Comment: Not really, duplicate values in zip and names create an error

Comment: So create a new distinct var, i.e. `df %>% mutate(new = row_number()) %>% spread(type, name)`

Comment: You are active on SO for quite some time now. Please learn how to post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). The problem can't be reproduced with the code you posted.

Comment: I edited my answer. Sorry for the quality of my post

Comment: `df %>% spread(type, name)` still returns the expected result without an error

Comment: I re-post and have Duplicate identifiers for rows

Comment: Just follow the link I duped it with. Did you try it? That is the solution to your problem (which by the way I found by hitting the FIRST link that came up after I googled *Error : Duplicate identifiers for rows*)

Comment: Your link resolve my problem.